# Creating two pygame screens using multiprocessing

Tags: python, pygame, python-multiprocessing, multi-window

I am trying to develop an app using pygame and I want to create a popup window.
I am trying to keep it all in one file, so I am using `multiprocessing` for this task.

I have two classes, the app and the popup window. Each one is inside a function that creates the windows and start both of their loops.

This is some simplified code:

main.py

```py
from multiprocessing import Process

def popup():
    import pygame as pg

    pg.init()

    class PopUp:
        def __init__(self):
            self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((300,300))

        def update(self):
            pg.display.flip()

    p = PopUp()
    while True:
        p.update()

def app():
    import pygame as pg

    pg.init()

    class App:
        def __init__(self):
            self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((800,600))
            self.create_popup()

        def create_popup(self):
            p = Process(target=popup)
            p.start()
            p.join()

        def update(self):
            pg.display.flip()

    a = App()
    while True:
        a.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Process(target=app)
    a.start()
    a.join()
```

However, when I execute this code, only one window appears, with the size of the App, and then is resized to the size of the PopUp, even though it is a different process.

If I do it this other way, then two separate windows will appear with no problem at all.

Why is this happening and how can I get to create the popup window from the app class?

Comment: You're duplicating the process after `pygame.init()` is called.  So probably they're sharing window handles, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're duplicating the process after `pygame.init()` is called.  So probably they're sharing window handles, etc.

If the process is copied before the `init()`, it works OK.

```
import multiprocessing
import pygame
import os

def handleUpdates( window, colour ):
    """ Simple pygame message loop.
        Paints the window in a single colour,
        handles quit event """
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    exiting = False

    while not exiting:
        # Handle user-input
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
                exiting = True

        # draw the window
        window.fill( colour )
        pygame.display.flip()

        # save CPU 
        clock.tick( 30 )

    pygame.quit()

def pyGameWindow( name, window_pos, colour ):
    """ Initialise PyGame for a new window """
    os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d,%d" % window_pos
    pygame.init()
    window  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( 300, 300 ) )
    pygame.display.set_caption( name )
    handleUpdates( window, colour )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=pyGameWindow, args=('Window One', ( 100, 100 ), (255, 0, 0 )))
    p1.start()
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=pyGameWindow, args=('Window Two', ( 500, 100 ), (255, 255, 0 )))
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```